# How to resolve System.OutOfMemoryException when loading large XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I have this code on my program that actually loads 500 MB and up files.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
```

I get this kind of error and don't know how to resolve the problem. Please send me some advice.

Comment: You may need to switch to a stream based XML parser.

Comment: And/or switch to actually loading smaller XML files.

Comment: @Matt can you show me some codes on how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I would use an `XmlReader` to parse the document, providing forward only access to the data and cleans itself up nicely in memory -- of course, it can be much more complex without the convenience of the `XmlDocument` class.

This simple sample will start by starting to read the file line by line, providing an XmlReader for each line.

```
using (var rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader("File.xml")))
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        //do what you will with the line
    }
}
```

See the methods and properties available to you when using the XmlReader at [XmlReader Properties (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader_properties.aspx)

Comment: in addition to the above codes I have the following:   XmlTextReader myTextReader = new XmlTextReader(txtFileName.Text); myTextReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None; while (myTextReader.Read()) { foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc) { TreeNode treeNode = XmlNode2TreeNode(myTextReader, myTextReader.p); treeNode.Text = FormatName(node); treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode); } }

Comment: added rudimentary sample to answer, mingzcky.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like SAX but for .NET.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxdotnet/ or the XmlReader, basically a stream based parser.

HTH